# Spreadsheet is no longer working in NeoOffice

Tags: imac

Spreadsheet is no longer working in NeoOffice. I've been using the free version since 2010. Why did this happen? What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/339710/edit) the question and specify the version of NeoOffice and macOS that you are running. Also share screenshots of any error message that you are receiving.

Comment: Also, does it only occur with one spreadsheet or with all? Did you recently upgrade macOS (or NeoOffice)? Did you check on neooffice.org already, especially https://neowiki.neooffice.org/index.php/NeoOffice_2017_Upgrade_Issues and https://neowiki.neooffice.org/index.php/Sierra,_High_Sierra,_and_Mojave_Upgrade_Issues?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I do not believe that I upgraded anything either OS or other software. I'm not sure but I believe I did take a screen shot of one of the error messages that I have received.

Comment: When I try to open a spreadsheet with NeoOffice the spreadsheet "disappears". I can't locate it any longer. There has not been a problem with word documents. I believe it is confined to spreadsheets. How do I upload screen shots to this forum?